# What is the value of Personal Injury Insurance riders on an auto insurance policy?

Tags: united-states, car-insurance

I'm renewing my auto insurance policy and found that +10% of the renewal quote is for a Personal Injury Protection.  My health insurance is adequate (for now) and the protection from the rider seems paltry ($10k medical/hospital per person, $2k funeral costs). From everything I've read online, I don't see the value of keeping the PIP rider.  Am I missing something?  Does this protect me if I'm transporting someone without health insurance or against personal liability (seems like the other riders should do that)?

I'm in Washington state and it doesn't look like the PIP rider is required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Quoted from https://www.dmv.org/insurance/personal-injury-protection.php

> Personal injury protection (or PIP, for short) is a type of medical payments coverage added on to an auto >insurance policy that provides you, the policyholder―as well as your passengers, relatives living in your home, >and drivers authorized to operate your vehicle―with medical coverage for immediate and subsequent injuries >sustained during an auto accident.
>
> PIP also covers you and your family if you’re injured in a car accident while in someone else’s vehicle and, in >some states, if you’re struck by a vehicle while you’re a pedestrian.

So if everyone you are driving with is covered by Personal Health Insurance, you may not need to go for this.